# Identifying pinch gesture drag gesture on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a small image on a view. The view is the object process multi-touch actions. If a finger drag on the view, the image will translate its position. And if user use 2 fingers to make pinch gesture, the image will scale its size. And I do work as section code below:

```
//touch detect methods

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
NSLog(@"Touch began");

//Devide into 2 cases: 1 touch and 2 touches. 
if ([touches count] == 1) {
    NSLog(@"Touch began cout = 1");
    currentImageCenter = focusImage.center;
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    previousPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    isTwoFingerTouching = FALSE;
}
else if([touches count] == 2){
    NSLog(@"Touch began cout = 2");
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    beginFirstPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
    beginSecondPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    isTwoFingerTouching = TRUE;
}

}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

if ([touches count] == 1 && isTwoFingerTouching == FALSE) {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
    CGPoint currentPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
    //Calculate distance
    double deltaX = currentPosition.x - previousPoint.x;
    double deltaY = currentPosition.y - previousPoint.y;
    NSLog(@"Touch move detect 1 touch ");
    focusImage.center = CGPointMake(currentImageCenter.x+deltaX, currentImageCenter.y+deltaY); 
}
else if([touches count] == 2){
    NSLog(@"Touch move detect 2 touches");
    CGPoint currentFirstPoint;
    CGPoint currentSecondPoint;
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
    currentFirstPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previousFirstPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];
    touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
    currentSecondPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    CGPoint previousSecondPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self];

    //Compare previous points with current points. 
    //Pinch gesture
    CGFloat beginDistance = distanceBetweenPoints(previousFirstPoint, previousSecondPoint);
    CGFloat currentDistance = distanceBetweenPoints(currentFirstPoint, currentSecondPoint);
    if (currentDistance > 0 && beginDistance > 0) {
        double scale = currentDistance/beginDistance;
        NSLog(@"%f", scale);
        //Rotation
        CGPoint vector1 = CGPointMake(previousFirstPoint.x - previousSecondPoint.x, previousFirstPoint.y - previousSecondPoint.y);
        CGPoint vector2 = CGPointMake(currentFirstPoint.x - currentSecondPoint.x, currentFirstPoint.y - currentSecondPoint.y);
        //[vector1, vector2]. 
        double zValue = vector1.x*vector2.y - vector1.y*vector2.x;

        CGFloat rotateAngle =  angleBetweenLines(previousFirstPoint, previousSecondPoint, currentFirstPoint, currentSecondPoint);
        //zValue < 0, vector1 rotate counter-clockwise, so the angle should be negative.

        if (zValue < 0) {
            rotateAngle = -rotateAngle;
        }
        //Don't allow to zoom out if the image is too small
        if (scale > 1 || focusImage.frame.size.width > 30) {
            CGAffineTransform previousTransform = focusImage.transform;
            CGAffineTransform mixTransform =  CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeScale(scale, scale), CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotateAngle));
            focusImage.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(previousTransform, mixTransform);
        }
    }
}
}
```

But the problem is: I can't identify whether 1 finger or 2 fingers on screen. When I touch 2 fingers, and I move (for rotate and scale) those fingers, `[touches count]` in `touchesMoved:` method still equal 1 occasionally. Any one experienced this, please tell me how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you are not using [UIGestureRecognizers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)? It will save you a lot of work if you just use a [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPanGestureRecognizer) and a [UIPinchGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPinchGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPinchGestureRecognizer).

In any case, iOS has always behaved like that. Unless you touch with both fingers at the exact same millisecond, you will detect a one finger touch first then detect two finger touch. You need to employ some sort of a cancelling mechanism in your code if you still want to go the -touchesBegan..., -touchesMoved..., etc., method.